# Notify NSFetchedResultsController of dynamic property change

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a NSManagedObject with a dynamic property, based on a relationship. I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` that fetches a list of these objects. However when the dynamic property changes, while KVO notifications are send out, the `NSFetchedResultsController` never calls it's delegate to reload the tableView.

```
- (BOOL)read
{
    return self.lastMessage.read;
}

- (void)setRead:(BOOL)read
{
    [self.messages enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(TSMessage *message, BOOL *stop) {
        message.read = read;
    }];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingRead
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"lastMessage.read"];
}
```

How do I force a change to be registered for the managedObject?

Answer (score 1):

In the Core Data Programming Guide, there is a whole [chapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW1) about custom accessors. In essence, you are responsible for calling the notification methods.

> If you want to implement your own attribute or to-one relationship accessor methods, you use the primitive accessor methods to get and set values from and to the managed object's private internal store. You must invoke the relevant access and change notification methods

Thus:

```
-(BOOL)read {
   [self willAccessValueForKey:@"read"];
   BOOL r = self.lastMessage.read;
   [self didAccessValueForKey:@"read"];
   return r;
}

-(void)setRead:(BOOL)read {
   [self willChangeValueForKey:@"read"];
   [self.messages enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(TSMessage *message, BOOL *stop) {
      message.read = read;
   }];
   [self didChangeValueForKey:@"read"];
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't update NSFetchedResultsController's delegate. And it doesn't cover the situation where the message read state is changed outside of these methods.

Comment: OK, then something is wrong with your setup. These methods are overriding your NSManagedObject subclass's getters and setters, so they should *always* be called if `read` changes - and they should notify any delegate. (Did you set the delegate?)

Comment: Yes I set the delegate. I am getting callback for all my properties defined in the model. It is only this property that is not causing a callback.